# Extrair parametros de uma consulta SQL

Tags: c#, microsoft

Na seguinte query em SQL qualquer

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE CAMPO1 = :PARAM1 AND CAMPO2 = :PARAM2
```

Eu preciso pegar os nomes desses parametros, `PARAM1` e `PARAM2` e armazena-los em uma lista ou array.

Para depois eu poder fazer um replace com os valores.

Como eu faço isso em C#?

Comment: pq você quer fazer replace ou invés de fazer o bind?

Comment: estou automatizando uns metodos com reflection, e quando eu passar uma query no parametro por exemplo, eu precisaria saber quais parametros . A grosso modo, eu mesmo vou fazer o bind manual da consulta.

Comment: Não seria o caso de pegar todos os `IndexOf` do caractere : e pegar o nome até encontrar um espaço?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da pra fazer utilizando expressões regulares:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE CAMPO1 = :PARAM1 AND CAMPO2 = AND CAMPO2 = :PARAM2";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(:+)(\S+)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);

List<string> parametros = new List<string>();
if (regex.IsMatch(query))
{
    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(query))
    {
        parametros.Add(match.Value);
    }
}
```

Exemplo funcional:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/rlaUwr

Comment: O que acontece se eu tiver a seguinte query: `SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE CAMPO1 = : AND CAMPO2 = :PARAM2`?

Comment: Vai dar match apenas no :PARAM2

Comment: Maravilha, isso funciona perfeitamente para o que preciso, obrigado